# Compiling Wireshark on Ubuntu outputs many redeclaration errors

Tags: 14.04, wireshark

I am trying to install Wireshark for ZBOSS in Ubuntu

When I try to rebuild, I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gdir.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:45,
                 from packet-gluster_cli.c:38:
packet-gluster.h:359:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_UNKNOWN'
  DT_UNKNOWN = 0,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:99:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_UNKNOWN' was here
     DT_UNKNOWN = 0,
     ^
packet-gluster.h:360:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_FIFO'
  DT_FIFO = 1,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:101:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_FIFO' was here
     DT_FIFO = 1,
     ^
packet-gluster.h:361:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_CHR'
  DT_CHR = 2,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:103:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_CHR' was here
     DT_CHR = 2,
     ^
packet-gluster.h:362:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_DIR'
  DT_DIR = 4,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:105:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_DIR' was here
     DT_DIR = 4,
     ^
packet-gluster.h:363:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_BLK'
  DT_BLK = 6,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:107:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_BLK' was here
     DT_BLK = 6,
     ^
packet-gluster.h:364:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_REG'
  DT_REG = 8,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:109:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_REG' was here
     DT_REG = 8,
     ^
packet-gluster.h:365:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_LNK'
  DT_LNK = 10,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:111:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_LNK' was here
     DT_LNK = 10,
     ^
...
...
packet-gluster.h:365:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_LNK'
  DT_LNK = 10,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:111:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_LNK' was here
     DT_LNK = 10,
     ^
packet-gluster.h:366:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_SOCK'
  DT_SOCK = 12,
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:113:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_SOCK' was here
     DT_SOCK = 12,
     ^
packet-gluster.h:367:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'DT_WHT'
  DT_WHT = 14
  ^
/usr/include/dirent.h:115:5: note: previous definition of 'DT_WHT' was here
     DT_WHT = 14
     ^
Makefile:6923 : la recette pour la cible « libdissectors_la-packet-gluster_pmap.lo » a échouée
make[5]: *** [libdissectors_la-packet-gluster_pmap.lo] Erreur 1
```

Any idea how can i solve it?

Comment: It would help if you wrote what command(s) generated above output.

Answer (score 2):

I got the this error when I was trying to compile Wireshark 1.8.8 on Ubuntu 18.04. I was able to compile wireshark successfully using fixes mentioned in this [link](https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/compiling-wireshark-1-8-8-on-fedora-25-64bit). The fixes are for fedora 25 however I tested it and it worked on Ubuntu 18.04 as well.

Here I put parts of the reference needed for a successful compilation (be careful, line numbers can be different for other versions). The first one solves your issue, however other (independent) issues will be raised afterwards as well and those can be fixed with the two other items listed.

- Edit `epan/dissectors/packet-gluster.h` and at line 357 delete the `gluster_entry_types` enum completely.
- Copy the definition of `g_memmove` from  `packaging/macosx/native-gtk/glibconfig.h` at line 81 and paste it on the first line of the files `ui/gtk/export_object_smb.c` and `epan/dissectors/packet-ssl-utils.c`. Here is the definition of `g_memmove` for convenience: `#define g_memmove(dest,src,len) G_STMT_START { memmove ((dest), (src), (len)); } G_STMT_END`.
- Update the file `AUTHORS` and replace the names `Peter Kovář`  with `Peter Kovar` and `Роман Донченко` with `Roman Donchenko` which are strings that only contain ASCII characters.